# How to add >-sign to expression in R?

Tags: r, expression, plotmath

I'd like to add a "greater than"-sign to an axis label.
The text shown should be `cumulated frequency p(>p[f]))`

I tried (amongst others):

```
title(mgp=c(2.50, 1, 0), cex.lab=1.25, xlab = expression("cumulated frequency" ~ p(>p[f]))) # xlab
```

But none of my trials worked - where is the mistake? Without having the `>` it works fine:

```
title(mgp=c(2.50, 1, 0), cex.lab=1.25, xlab = expression("cumulated frequency" ~ p(p[f]))) # xlab
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>` is a binary operator. Thus, it needs something on its left side. For example a "dummy"-null-label `{}`:

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, xlab=expression("frequency"~p({}>p[f])))
```

Also, e.g. `phantom()`, `plain()`, etc. may be used to print "nothing".

If you don't want spaces around `<`, try:

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, main=expression("test"~p(paste(">",p[f]))))
```

or for a more "mathematical" `<`:

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, main=expression("test"~p(paste(symbol(">"),p[f]))))
```

Comment: Is there also a way to remove the spaces before and after the `>`-sign? With RichardScrivens solution I can do it, but the `>`-sign in the text-mode looks ugly. And in the plotmath-mode spaces are added,...

Comment: In your second solution is like the one of RichardScriven. The `>` is much larger than the the one in your first solution. Would be nice to have the small `>` without spaces,... :)

Comment: @R_User: What about `symbol(">")` - this gives a more "mathematical symbol"-like `>`?

Answer (score 1):

this might work for you:

```
plot.new()
title(mgp = c(2.50, 1, 0), cex.lab = 1.25, 
      xlab = expression(paste("cumulated frequency p(>", p[f], ")")))
```